# Displaying an image from summary block on text hover using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, squarespace

I am working in Squarespace and quite new to Javascript and HTML.

In the screenshot below you could see that I am trying to create an effect that when you hover on one of the titles on the left, the image on the right in summary block changes. Since I am learning as I go I have created a code block for the titles and included a javascript in there as well. I assigned a id number to each title corresponding to the photo. However I just can not figure out how to make it work. All the info came from expecting other websites and seeing what code they are using. Could someone help me where I am going wrong - probably all sorts of things :-(

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7Hvq.jpg)

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $( window ).ready(function() {
                   var screenRes = $(window).width();
               $(window).resize(function () {
                screenRes = $(window).width();
        });
        setTimeout(function(){
            if (screenRes >= 768) {
                jQuery('.summary-item-list .summary-item').each(function(){
                    var ids = jQuery(this).attr('id');
                    console.log(ids);
                    $(this).find('.summary-title').attr('data-id', ids);
                    var link = $(this).find('.summary-title-link').attr('href');
                    if (typeof link !== 'undefined') {
                        $(this).find('.summary-title a').wrapInner('<span></span>');
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).find('.summary-title').wrapInner('<span></span>');
                    }
                    $(this).find('.summary-title').appendTo('.gallery-titles');
                });
                jQuery('.gallery-titles .summary-title:first-of-type').addClass('active');
                var dataid = $('.gallery-titles .summary-title:first-of-type').data('id');
                var link = $('#' + dataid + ' .summary-title-link').attr('href');
                $('#' + dataid).addClass('active');

                jQuery('.gallery-titles .summary-title').on("mouseover", (function(){
                    jQuery('.gallery-titles .summary-title').removeClass("active");
                    jQuery('.summary-item').removeClass("active");
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                    var dataid = $(this).data('id');
                    console.log(dataid);
                    $('#' + dataid).addClass('active');
                }))
            }
            }, 200);
     if (screenRes < 768) {
         $('.summary-item-list').slick({
             slide: '.summary-item',
             infinite: true,
             centerMode: false,
             slidesToShow: 1,
             autoplay: false,
             dots: false,
             fade: true,
             cssEase: 'linear',
             lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
         });
     }
});
</script>

<div class="gallery-titles">
  

<div class="summary-title" data-id="yui_3_17_2_1_1599508505867_11534">
  <a href="/blog/tempus-blandit" class="summary-title-link">
    <span>Tempus blandit</span>
  </a>
</div>
  
  <div class="summary-title" data-id="yui_3_17_2_1_1599508505867_11536">
  <a href="/blog/Tempus-porttitor" class="summary-title-link">
    <span>Tempus porttitor</span>
  </a>
</div>
  
  <div class="summary-title" data-id="yui_3_17_2_1_1599508505867_11538">
  <a href="/blog/Curabitur-blandit" class="summary-title-link">
    <span>Curabitur blandit</span>
  </a>
</div>

  <div class="summary-title" data-id="yui_3_17_2_1_1599508505867_11540">
  <a href="/blog/Curabitur-blandit-tempus-porttitor" class="summary-title-link">
    <span>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor</span>
  </a>
</div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice pure CSS solution:

```css
p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
p:hover {
  color:red;
}
#image {
  position: absolute;
  right:1vw;
  top:0;
  width: 70vw;
  height:40vh;
}
#a:hover ~ #image {
  background: url("x") red;
}
#b:hover ~ #image {
  background: url("y") green;
}
#c:hover ~ #image {
  background: url("z") blue;
}
```

```html
<p id="a">Image Description 1</p>
<p id="b">Image Description 2</p>
<p id="c">Image Description 3</p>
<img id="image" />
```

Of course you should replace

```css
background: url("y") green;
```

with

```css
background: url("/path/to/image/");
```

Comment: Wow thank you Nate. You are completely right, I think I was overthinking this :-)
I only have one question - When the mouse is not over the text nothing is displayed. If I am using CSS is there a way once I hover an item, the image will stay until the next item is hovered?

Comment: @Uli You would have to use javascript for that. Something like `text.onmouseover = ()=>{image.style.background = 'url("/path/to/image/")';}`